# Error with validates_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Given the following code in an initializer:

```
module ValidatesAssociatedAttributes
  module ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods
    def validates_associated(*associations)
      class_eval do
        validates_each(associations) do |record, associate_name, value|
            #empty for now
        end
      end
    end
 end
end
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:message=>nil}:Hash
```

I am stumped. As far as I can tell, associations has the expected data. Usually when I start getting to_sym errors it means there is something misconfigured, but in this case, I am just using a plain jane validates_associated. I don't get what/why something needs to be to_sym'd.

Comment: Posting an error without a stack trace is like telling a joke but leaving out the punchline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after more clearly reading the API I found where I flubbed it:
I needed to splat associations for validates_each to receive everything in the proper order:

```
module ValidatesAssociatedAttributes
  module ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods
    def validates_associated(*associations)
      class_eval do
        validates_each(*associations) do |record, associate_name, value|
            #empty for now
        end
      end
    end
 end
end
```